# Finding pairs of racers where racer `a` have beaten racer `b` in all races

Tags: c++

I've got a challenge and I would like to ask you to guide me a little. I have number `n` (number of racers)and two lines containing `n` integers(the integer actually represents the racer) each. Those lines represent order in which racers have ended the race.

I have to find all doubles/pairs where a racer `a` have beaten racer `b` in both races. Can You guide me a bit?

Example

```
Input : 
3
1 2 3
2 3 1
Output :1 (only 2 and 3 have met the condition)
```

Comment: What's the "length" of an integer?? What does "finding doubles" mean?

Comment: sorry, it meant to be n integers in line

Comment: Easy, treat the integers as strings.  Use `std::string::length()`.

Comment: oops there should be space :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, finding the length of a number is very simple. In c++, it is just `ceil(log10(number))` when using math.h.  On to your code, you can use a very simple function to turn the input of numbers into a vector.  For example:

```
//input number of racers (int racerNum)
//input number of races (int raceNum)
vector<vector<int>> result(raceNum, vector<int>(racerNum));
for (int race=0; race<raceNum; race++){
    //input race results as one string of integers without spaces (int rResult)
    int curVal = rResult;
    for (int place = racerNum-1, input=0; place >= 0; place--, input++){
        curVal = floor(rResult/pow(10,place));
        result.at(race).at(place) = curVal;
        rResult -= curVal*pow(10, place);
    }
}
```

Or, you may want to use the example you had before, where you input the results with spaces.  This will allow you to have more than 9 racers, and it is probably simpler.  It utilizes the fact that cin will separate a string with spaces into smaller strings. For example:

```
//get number of racers (int racerNum)
//get number of races (int raceNum)
vector<vector<int>> raceResults;
for (int race=0; race<raceNum; race++){
    vector<int> singleResult;
    cout << "Results of race " << race+1 << ":";
    //get input with spaces
    for (int counter=0; counter<racerNum; counter++){
        int result;
        cin >> result;
        singleResult.push_back(result);
    }
    raceResult.push_back(singleResult);
}
```

I would recommend the second example, but the first will also work just as well.  The first is just the purely mathematical approach, and the second utilizes the way cin gets input.  Either way, you will be left with a vector or races, each of which is a vector of the results, in the proper order.  I think that this should be enough to get you started, but if you need any help with the rest of the code or with this code, I can help.

Comment: thank you, this works like a charm. But is there more efficient way of checking? because if I use linear search, it will have to cycle throught it for many times. check how many pairs exist for first racer, then 2nd,3rd  and so on.

Comment: @Roi lam I'm glad that the code works, but I think that a linear search will be the most efficient, even with large races.